# In Virtual Populate, how do you define foreignField?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

Consider the code below:

```
 require("./connection");

// //----------------------------------------------------
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PersonSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  band: String,
  father: String
});

const ManagerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  country: String
});

const BandSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

BandSchema.virtual("members", {
  ref: "Person", // The model to use
  localField: "name", // Find people where `localField`
  foreignField: "band", // is equal to `foreignField`
  // If `justOne` is true, 'members' will be a single doc as opposed to
  // an array. `justOne` is false by default.
  justOne: false,
  options: { sort: { name: -1 }, limit: 5 } 
});

BandSchema.virtual("managers", {
  ref: "Manager", // The model to use
  localField: "name", // Find people where `localField`
  foreignField: "country", // is equal to `foreignField`
  // If `justOne` is true, 'members' will be a single doc as opposed to
  // an array. `justOne` is false by default.
  justOne: false,
  options: { sort: { name: 1 }, limit: 5 } 
});

//BandSchema.set("toObject", { virtuals: true });
BandSchema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", PersonSchema);
const Manager = mongoose.model("Manager", ManagerSchema);

const Band = mongoose.model("Band", BandSchema);

/**
 * Suppose you have 2 bands: "Guns N' Roses" and "Motley Crue"
 * And 4 people: "Axl Rose" and "Slash" with "Guns N' Roses", and
 * "Vince Neil" and "Nikki Sixx" with "Motley Crue"
 */
// Person.create([
//   {
//     name: "Axl Rose",
//     band: "Guns N' Roses"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Slash",
//     band: "Guns N' Roses"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Vince Neil",
//     band: "Motley Crue"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Nikki Sixx",
//     band: "Motley Crue"
//   }
// ]);

// Manager.create([
//   {
//     name: "Bibi",
//     country: "South Africa"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Storm",
//     country: "Italy"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Wolverine",
//     country: "Canada"
//   },
//   {
//     name: "Jorge Pires",
//     country: "Brazil"
//   }
// ]);

// Band.create([{ name: "Motley Crue" }, { name: "Guns N' Roses" }]);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const app = require("express")();

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  Band.find({})
    .populate("members")
    .populate("managers")
    .exec(function(error, bands) {
      /* `bands.members` is now an array of instances of `Person` */
      console.log(bands);
      res.json(bands);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("We are on port 3000");
});

/**
 *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882577/mongoosejs-virtual-populate
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875380/populate-virtuals-does-not-seem-to-work-could-anyone-show-me-the-error
 */
```

Consider the related questions:

- [Mongoosejs virtual populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882577/mongoosejs-virtual-populate)
- [Populate Virtuals does not seem to work. Could anyone show me the error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875380/populate-virtuals-does-not-seem-to-work-could-anyone-show-me-the-error)

My question is: **how do you define `foreignField`?**

`Members` populate properly, but *manager does not*.

I know the problem is `foreignField` because if I repeat all the information from members, it will populate properly, but now we have members and manage with the same data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some studies, trying to answer another question here on Stack Overflow ([mongoose: populate in mongoose which doesn't have any ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174212/mongoose-populate-in-mongoose-which-doesnt-have-any-objectid/61174796#61174796)
), I realized how it works!

Consider part of the code presented:

```
BandSchema.virtual("members", {
  ref: "Person", // The model to use
  localField: "name", // Find people where `localField`
  foreignField: "band", // this field here has to match the ref path we want to populate!      
  justOne: false,

});
```

So, the trick is to make sure `foreignField` match the field at the `ref` model, and `localField` is the name of the field that you can find at the populated model: we must have a match between `foreignField` and `localField`, more precisely: the value of `localField` has to match the one of  `foreignField` in real situation, in the database, not in the schema naming process. That is how mongoose can find and populate!

What now I realise I was having difficult is that `Virtual` operates somehow in the opposite direction of `populate`. You can picture populate by working as a tree: it just populate from the `id` to the document, whereas `virtual` will populate the document that does not contain the key, the one that contain the key is the one to be added in the populate process: it is somehow backward, that is it was so hard to me to grasp! The document to be populated does not have the field just populated! it is mind-blowing!

**Conclusion and final remarks**

Nonetheless, I still find it limited compared to `populate`. You still must keep local key tracks, which does not solve for instance the story memory issue, and it is more limited according to my studies. The only advantage I see is that you do not need to use the `_id`, you can use any key you please. I was hoping to use to solve my problem here [How to save an JSON file using GridFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968353/how-to-save-an-json-file-using-gridfs), but since we still have to store local keys, I fall into de same trap!

**Correction**

*I am glad to say that I was wrong!* Virtuals is awsome! and solves my probem on [How to save an JSON file using GridFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968353/how-to-save-an-json-file-using-gridfs), I am going to update there!