# Virtual populate with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following shema, how to populate document from Media for education, experience, and certification? I have tried many ways but it does not work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.User = schema => {
  schema.add({
    username: {
      type: String,
      index: true
    },
    education: [
      {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        year: String,
        verified: Boolean,
        documentId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    ],
    experience: [
      {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        year: String,
        verified: Boolean,
        documentId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    ],
    certification: [
      {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        year: String,
        verified: Boolean,
        documentId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    ]
  });
  schema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
  schema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the path attribute for deep linking, this would work for Array types too.

> **Step 1:** Change the schema of documentId field as below to **define
> reference** to the Media Collection

```
documentId: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: 'Media' },
```

> **Step 2:** **Define virtual properties** on the schema

```
schema.virtual('educationDocument', {   
    ref: 'Media', // the collection/model name
    localField: 'education.documentId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true, // default is false });
```

> **Step 3:** Use mongoose **populate with path definition** for deep linking

```
const users = await User.find({})
    .populate({ path: 'educationDocument' })
    .populate({ path: 'experienceDocument' })
    .populate({ path: 'certificationDocument' })
    .execPopulate()
```

Comment: Thanks you,  but education is an array.
education: [
      {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        year: String,
        verified: Boolean,
        documentId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    ]

Comment: It should work for Array Types too. Or you can try const users = await User.find({})
    .populate({ path: 'education.documentId' }) without using virtuals just ensure you define schema as in Step 1

Answer (score 0):

check [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
const users = await User.find({}).populate('education').populate('experience').populate('certification')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need populate Document by documentId of education, experience or certification. Do you have any more solutions?
==> check this: documentId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId